# COUNTIF Unique Dates Between a Range

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to find a way to `COUNTIF(S)` between a certain set of dates, but only get the count of the unique dates.  For context, I am tracking meters over days.  I can get more than one instance on the same day with differing meter values.  The fact that can happen is screwing up my meters/day average.

`Data!A3:A8700` - is the date range.

I am summarizing things monthly, so, in this case, for this example, I'd like something that:

1) Uses `COUNTIF` (or anything that will work!) between date x and date y.  Would like X and Y stored to be pulled from `DATA!A3:A8700`.  In this case, for instance, 11/1/2014 = x and 11/31/2014 = y

2) I would ONLY like to get unique dates as a valid part of the count:

```
11/1/2014
11/2/2014
11/2/2014
11/3/2014
```

Would return 3, for instance, not 4.

I have found solutions to get unique numbers in the entire column, but nothing yet for a range within that column.  Or, more accurately, I have not been able to figure out how to properly modify those.

Comment: Could you just subtract min(A3:A8700) from max(a3:a8700), or do you have days that are skipped?

Comment: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(Data!A3:A8700,Data!A3:A8700)>0,1))` should do the trick. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Comment: But I need JUST the frequency of numbers BETWEEN two dates.  That will just give the me the unique frequency of ALL the numbers, right?

Comment: Are the dates in a3:A8700 in order?

Comment: Yes from most recent to least recent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65242/discussion-between-chow-and-jnevill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the following, tell me if I am wrong:
[image]

That is, starting from ***01/11/2014*** that is in **D1** and ending in ***12/11/2014*** that is in **D2**, you want to calculate unique dates that fall inbetween these **two dates** in your **A1:A100** range. 
And in this example, there are 6 unique dates, as shown in result cell **D4**.
Here is the formula to count unique values (dates) in column containing a series of dates.

***the formula***:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$1:$A$97>=D$1;IF($A$1:$A$97<=D$2;IF($A$1:$A$97<>"";MATCH($A$1:$A$97;$A$1:$A$97;0))));ROW($A$1:$A$97)-ROW($A$1)+1);1))
```

you may need to adjust it according to your **regional settings**, by replacing **";"** with **","**.

**here is** [the example excel sheet to download from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueo8jhuyezsdp4i/unique%20countifs_example.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Works perfectly -- thanks!  Had to turn it into an array formula though, so CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to get it to work.