# How to get Frequency of days between date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have the following Array formula getting the frequency of days per Fleet Number(this is over all and not linked to any date):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Management Ops Sheet'!$B$8:$B$500=A6,'Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500),'Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500)>0,1))
```

Below is a breakdown of what each part represents :

`'Management Ops Sheet'!$B$8:$B$500` is the list of Fleet numbers

`A6` is the fleet number im checking for

`'Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500` is the list of dates

I have a date range I want to work from:

`Cell B3` is the Date From

`Cell C3` is the Date To

What I want to do is get the frequency of the days between(and including) the above dates.

Below is the data I am searching through:

[image]

```
| Date      | Fleet No. |   |   |   |
|-----------|:---------:|---|---|---|
| 01-Mar-18 | H05       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H05       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H05       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H05       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H72       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H72       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H77       |   |   |   |
| 01-Mar-18 | H86       |   |   |   |
| 02-Mar-18 | H05       |   |   |   |
| 02-Mar-18 | H72       |   |   |   |
| 03-Mar-18 | H77       |   |   |   |
| 03-Mar-18 | H86       |   |   |   |
| 04-Apr-18 | H86       |   |   |   |
```

Below is where I am using the formula:

[image]

```
| Month:    |          2018-02-01      |     2018-03-01       |                   |   |
|-----------|:------------------------:|----------------------|-------------------|---|
| TOTAL     |  R           56,043.50   | 6745                 | 2.25              |   |
| Fleet No. | Turnover   Month to Date | KM's   Month to Date | Days   Worked M/D |   |
| H05       |  R             3,097.50  | 645                  | 2                 |   |
| H72       |  R           19,864.00   | 2200                 | 2                 |   |
| H77       |  R           20,132.00   | 1400                 | 2                 |   |
| H86       |  R           12,950.00   | 2500                 | 3                 |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
|           |                          |                      |                   |   |
```

I dont know how to change the formula to get this to work. If  any one is able to help I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!!

Comment: What frequency? Naturally all days are only once in a calender?

Comment: The list I am searching through allows a fleet number to different loads on the same day. So if multiple loads were done on 2018-04-05 then the frequency will be 1. If loads were done on 2 different days(doesnt matter how many per day) then the frequency will be 2, and so on. Does this make sense ?

Comment: In most cases providing a sample of your data is very helpfull, this case would be one of them.

Comment: My apologies, I should have done that from the beginning. I have updated my question. I hope this helps make more sense on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Just thinking about this, your data looks fine to make use of a pivot table, that would solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: In this case unfortunately not. I am pulling data from different sheets in other columns which require some other complex formulas. So I would like to be able to just change this one formula, or even use a different formula to provide what I need.

Comment: If you make the pivottable, and then do vlookup on the pivottable you can maintain your current layout whilst benefiting from the ease of the pivottable.

Comment: @QHarr, thanks for the reply. The screen shots I added give some data and expected results. the Days Worked M/D is currently the result, but as mentioned this is overall and I want it to work based on the dates highlighted in yellow

Comment: So taking HO5 as an example: for the shown data what should the result be? Also, it helps to include data using a tool such as [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to format your data, which you then insert between code tags, so people can copy your data. Can't do that with an image.

Comment: So for H05 it should be showing 2. If I added a new date for H05(such as 4 April), then the result should stay 2, unless I change the "To Date" to April(i.e. searching for between Feb and April, it should then show 3. I tried the Table generator and pasting it in my question didnt show in a viewable format...maybe im just being dumb ;)

Comment: Wow you learn something new every day, thanks QHarr. I have updated. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it sorted out!! Thanks to @Luuklag and @QHarr that tried helping me out.

The formula I landed up using was as follows:

```
=IF(A6<>"",SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(MONTH('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500)>=MONTH(B$3),IF(MONTH('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500)<=MONTH(C$3),IF('Management Ops Sheet'!$B$8:$B$500=A6,IF('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500<>"",MATCH('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500,'Management Ops Sheet'!$A$8:$A$500,0))))),ROW('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$7:$A$500)-ROW('Management Ops Sheet'!$A$7)+1),1)),"")
```

Please note that this is an Array Formula, so you need to push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for this formula to work.

The following post actually helped me in the right direction: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021006/countif-unique-dates-between-a-range)